# Converting EBCDIC to persian characters in c#

Tags: c#, ascii, persian, ebcdic

I use [this implementation](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/ebcdic) of converting EBCDIC to ASCII. this solution is OK for English characters. But I want to use it for Persian[or Arabic] characters. It doesn't work correctly for Persian characters. Do you know another solution?

Comment: What is your question? Can you show the actual code, input and (expected) output?

Comment: Are you converting old legacy contents to Persian/Arabic? Would describe your need a bit more?

Comment: Use Encoding.GetEncoding("IBM420") for Arabic.  Farsi is not supported.